# Deriving the form of generators of transformations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, unitarity

I'm struggling to understand a bit of quantum mechanics relating to the transformation generators. This specific bit contains quite a few guesses and assumtions which probably do make sense in hindsight, but not so much during the first read. Here it is.

[image]

My first question is about the bit in orange. I understand that $g_\alpha$ is something like a, say, rotation, where in this example the parameter $\alpha$ is the angle of rotation. Then the meaning of the expansion 8.2.4 is 'if $\alpha = 0$, leave the object A as it was, otherwise add corrections proportional to orders of $\alpha$'. Is this a correct way of thinking about this? If so, doesn't 8.2.4 need some justification? Why is it kay to just assume this?

The second thing is the equation 8.2.12. The author suggests that it can be deduced from the commutation relation above it, but I can't see how that is the case. When the form of Q is assumed in 8.2.7, the differential is evaluated at $\alpha = 0$. The commutation relation gives:

$QU = i\hbar \frac{\partial U(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}\biggr\rvert_{\alpha = 0} U = UQ = QU$

and I can't see how i) the derivative (rather than just a number, i.e. an evaluated derivative) arises ii) the extra U on the LHS vanishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Eq.(8.2.4) assumes the corrections in $\alpha$ depend just on A, and not on any other quantities. The explicit form of the dependence is not really important at this point and it is left as $f(A)$.
2. As for Eq,(8.2.12), start with
   $$
   U(\alpha +\delta\alpha) = U(\delta\alpha)U(\alpha)
   $$
   and substitute the 1st of Eqs.(8.2.8) for $U(\delta\alpha)$, neglecting $O(\delta\alpha^2)$:
   $$
   U(\alpha +\delta\alpha) \approx \left( \mathbb{I} - \frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\alpha Q \right)U(\alpha) = U(\alpha)  - \frac{i}{\hbar}\delta\alpha Q U(\alpha)
   $$
   Rearrange as
   $$
   \frac{1}{\delta\alpha}\left[ U(\alpha +\delta\alpha) - U(\alpha) \right] = - \frac{i}{\hbar} Q  U(\alpha)
   $$
   and take $\delta\alpha \rightarrow 0$ to obtain
   $$
   \frac{\partial U(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha} = - \frac{i}{\hbar} Q  U(\alpha)
   $$
   Done. Keep in mind the difference between $\frac{\partial U(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}$ and $Q = i\hbar \frac{\partial U(\alpha=0)}{\partial \alpha}$.